# Integration using trigonometric substitution: integrate $\sqrt{4-x^2}$.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometric-integrals

I need to integrate $\sqrt{4-x^2}$ but every time I check my answer with an online calculator I get a different answer back.

Here's what I get: $2u-\sin(2u)+C$

Can anyone confirm that my answer is correct? I have gone over the whole question three times now.

Thank you.

Comment: what is your $u$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: After doing a trig substitution I put it into terms of theta, but used "u" instead of it for this question. Here's where it gets transformed: x = 2sin(theta)

Comment: Should be $2 \theta+ sin(2 \theta)+C$ where $x=2 \sin(\theta)$ ... Now you just need to go back to the original variable using  $x=2 \sin(\theta)$

Comment: Sure, I know θ should be used, but the answer I got (using "u" instead) is correct?

Comment: The answer is towards the bottom above the graph: https://www.symbolab.com/solver/indefinite-integral-calculator/%5Cint%5Csqrt%7B4-x%5E%7B2%7D%7Ddx

Comment: The difference between my expression and yours is I have a + in front of the sin part, that's the only difference before the switcharoo with the original variable.

Comment: Would you be able to reply to my question and show what exactly you did? I'm just learning this stuff, and I cannot find a good example of a problem like this.

Comment: May I see exactly what you integrated (the step before the step that said hey you can lose that $\int$ thing) ?  I would like to see if I can analyze your work to help you find the error.

Comment: Ok: https://imgur.com/a/PKGFQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only mistake is when doing $\int \cos(2 \theta) d \theta$ you should get $\frac{1}{2} \sin(2 \theta)+C$

Congrats you aren't that bad at this! :)

Comment: Great! Thank you for your help. It is always good to hear that you're not _that_ bad at something.

Comment: lol :p Well you said you were new to this... lol... It seemed like you might have had doubts about your ability when you said that.

Comment: Hey! I like to draw a right triangle for $\sin(\theta)=\frac{x}{2}$ to help me find what the other trig functions should be in terms of $x$... You know to help with the $\sin(2\theta)$ part... since that is equal to $2 \sin(\theta) cos(\theta)$

Comment: I see. I forgot that after that I need to go the other way. Let me see If I can figure this out on my own real quick.

Comment: I can't seem to figure out the right way to draw the triangle. Would it be that opp = x, hyp = 2, and adj = sqrt{4-x^2} What is the general way to figure what goes where?

Comment: yes, that is correct! Now you are ready to find $\cos(\theta)$ in terms of $x$.. When you get a chance, take a look at paul's site: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/TrigSubstitutions.aspx you know for later when you are in the right math meditative mood.

Answer (score 4):

$$ \int\sqrt{(4-x^2)}dx$$

$$As \ you \ said: let \ x=2sin(\theta) => dx=2cos(\theta)d\theta \ so \ we \ have $$

$$ \int\sqrt{(4-4sin^2(\theta))}\ 2cos(\theta)d\theta=\int2\sqrt{1-sin^2(\theta)}\ 2cos(\theta)d\theta=4\int\cos^2(\theta)d\theta=4\int\frac{(1+cos(2\theta)}{2}d\theta=2\theta+sin(2\theta)+C=2arcsin(\frac{x}{2})+sin(2arcsin(x/2))+C$$

$$ Ok\ now \ for \ sin(2arcsin(x/2)) $$

$$ Let \ y=arcsin(x/2) \ and \ x/2=siny \ so \ we \ have \ sin(2y)=2sin(y)*cos(y)=x*\sqrt{(1-\frac{x^2}{4})}=\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}  $$

$$ Final \ answer\ : \int\sqrt{(4-x^2)}=2arcsin(\frac{x}{2})+\frac{x}{2}\sqrt{4-x^2}+C $$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I only got to 2θ+sin(2θ)+C. I'm not even sure what is happening after that, could you explain what rules you are using, so I can see if I have learned them yet. Am I supposed to substitute something back?

Comment: After that we need to substitute x back in  now, so from $$ x=2sin(\theta) \ 
 we \  need \  \theta=arcsin(x/2) $$ because we started with an integral in x variables